# Setting StringVar() not setting string within variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

The following is the functional issue I'm dealing with. While this example doesn't do it, word is being set by a for loop, so I can't just set "dave" with a string. However, if you run it, you can see that "word" is printing "smith" and "dave" is printing "PYVAR0." How can I fix it so "dave" prints "smith"?

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
root = Tk()
word = "smith"
print word
dave = StringVar()
dave.set(word)
print dave
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke [`dave.get`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm):

```
print dave.get()
```

Doing so will return the string value contained in the `StringVar`.